# Post to Twitter using Terminal with CURL

Tags: unix, curl, twitter, terminal

I got this far:

```
:~ curl -u username:password -d status="new_status" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

Now, how can I alias this with variables so I can easily twit from Terminal? How can I make the alias working through different sessions (when I close Terminal aliases reset).

Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, no longer works and has not for several years. There should be a way to mark questions as anachronistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clearly have the alias command: stick it in your ~/.bashrc and it will be set up when your bash shell starts.  (.shrc should also work for sh-like shells.)

If you stick it in a script file as the previous answer suggests:

(a) add the line

```
#!/bin/sh
```

at the top;

(b) make sure it's on your path or you'll have to type the whole path to the script when you want to run it.

(c) to make it executable,

```
chmod +x tweet.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

Basic Authentication is no longer supported by twitter. Please use OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

what about putting it a file and using argument 1 as $1:

```
# tweet.sh "post my status, moron!":
curl -u username:password -d status="$1" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml
```

will that work?

Comment: whenever I do this I always get a space, it ends up doing "-d status=" mystatus".  any tips to remove the space added in the $1 variable?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a file in your home directory that will get referenced each time a new terminal opens.

Do a bit of research as to what to name the file, according to what type of shell you are using (tcsh looks for a file called .tcshrc while bash looks for .bashrc).

Once you have that file, make it executable by running:

```
chmod +x name_of_file
```

Then, in that file, create your alias (again, you'll need to research how to do this depending on what type of shell you are using).  For tcsh, my alias looks like this:

```
alias tw 'curl -u username:password -d status=\!^ http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml'
```

Bash aliases use an equals sign.  A bash alias would look something more like this:

```
alias tw='curl -u username:password -d status=\!^ http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml'
```

Note the change in the command after "status=".  The `\!^` tells the line of code to insert the first argument passed after the alias itself.

Save your file.

You could then run an update to twitter by typing the following in a new terminal:

```
tw 'my first post to twitter via the terminal, using aliases'
```

Don't forget to escape 'special' characters (like exclamations) with the escape character, `\` (i.e. `\!`)

Answer (score 1):

Since Basic Authentication is no longer supported by twitter, you have to use OAuth to achieve your goal.

But if you just want to post to Twitter using terminal, there are many application can do it.
Take a look at [Rainbowstream](https://github.com/DTVD/rainbowstream) or [t](https://github.com/sferik/t)

With rainbowstream, the following lines will let you tweet from console:

```
$ sudo pip install rainbowstream
$ rainbowstream
[@yourscreenname]t whatever you want
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @Hidde. I added the details in my answer